# Why occur holding of Tez Queue in HiveServer2?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

I use Python and Thrift for running queries on Tez engine in separated Queue (Fair Scheduler) through HiveServer2. And some queries stopping on `Choosing a session from the defaultQueuePool`, but queue is empty.

```
...
15/12/07 12:57:11 INFO ql.Driver: Query ID = hadoop_20151207125711_3060df1a-1eda-4b60-9688-a2fe78573125
15/12/07 12:57:11 INFO ql.Driver: Total jobs = 1
15/12/07 12:57:11 INFO log.PerfLogger: 
15/12/07 12:57:11 INFO log.PerfLogger: 
15/12/07 12:57:11 INFO log.PerfLogger: 
15/12/07 12:57:11 INFO ql.Driver: Launching Job 1 out of 1
15/12/07 12:57:11 INFO ql.Driver: Starting task [Stage-1:MAPRED] in serial mode
15/12/07 12:57:11 INFO tez.TezSessionPoolManager: Choosing a session from the defaultQueuePool
```

Why that may be?

Answer (score 1):

Working through the same issue.  In your existing session, Set tez.queue.name to some other queue and then retry your original command... In my case it worked.  Seems as if it reinitialized the session pool which was being blocked.  I'm still trying to reproduce this and also experimenting with some cfg changes